# Rails param value with anchor appended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following link

```
<%= link_to "Login to comment", :url => new_session_url(:return_to => request.request_uri, :anchor => 'commentForm'), :method => :get, :html => { :id => 'login_to_comment'} %>
```

generates the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/session/new?return_to=%2Fnature_photos%2Fsdfds#commentForm
```

and the parameters are as below from the logs.

```
Processing SessionsController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-07-16 02:04:44) [GET]
Parameters: {"return_to"=>"/nature_photos/sdfds", "action"=>"new", "controller"=>"sessions"}
Completed in 74721ms (View: 15, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://localhost/session/new?return_to=%2Fnature_photos%2Fsdfds]
```

Here I need that #commentForm anchor is excluded from the parameter return_to

I need to get that value to scroll down to the comment form at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `#` is unescaped, the anchor `#commentForm` is actually part of the URL `/session/new?return_to=...`, and **not part of the URL `/nature_photos/sdfds`** (which is given as the value of `return_to` in the query string). This happens because you use the `:anchor` option in `new_session_url`: it will add the anchor to the complete URL. Note that the anchor is never sent to the server!

What you are probably looking for is the following:

```
:url => new_session_url(:return_to => request.request_uri + "#commentForm"), ...
```

This will append the anchor directly to the URL that is the value of `return_to`, which implies that the `#` character should be URI escaped to `%23`. When it is sent back to the server as the parameter `return_to`, it is unescaped and you can use it as a regular URL again.